# Dickson's Lemma

Tags: commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals

I am doing a course in Commutative algebra and there is a lemma called Dickson's lemma which states the following:

> Let $\mathfrak{I} = \langle X^{u}: u \in A\rangle$ for some set $A \subset \mathbb{N}^{n}$. Then $\exists$   $u_{1},u_{2},\dots u_{s}$ such that $\mathfrak{I} = \langle X^{u_{1}},X^{u_{2}},\dots, X^{u_{s}}\rangle$.  Here $X^{u}$ is a monomial in the polynomial ring $k[x_{1}, \dots x_{n}]$ and $\mathfrak{I}$ is a monomial ideal.

So what Dickson's lemma is saying is that every monomial ideal in $k[x_1, \dots x_n]$ has a finite generating set. However I also looked at the definition given in Wikipedia and there Dickson's lemma is given as the following:

> Dickson's lemma states that every set of $n$-tuples of natural numbers has finitely many minimal elements

I am sure they both mean the same thing,  but I don't know why that is so and I can't link the definition given in Wikipedia to the one I have. Could someone explain in simple terms what Dickson's lemma really means and how it applies to the original definition I gave right at the start.

Answer (score 1):

You should verify, that $\langle X^u | u \in A \rangle = \langle X^u | u \in B \rangle$ where $B \subset A$ is the set of minimal elements of $A$. Then the equivalence of the two formulations of Dickson's Lemma becomes clear, since the cited version states that $B$ is finite.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what minimal means in the context of monomials.

Comment: You have a partial ordering and minimal in such a context always means that there is no element, which is sctrictly smaller.

Comment: Ok, so suppose we have a term ordering on the set of monmials, doesn't this make the set of monomials totally ordered? and therefore we have  a minimum element?

Comment: We consider the pointwise partial ordering here. This is not a total ordering.

Comment: @user1314 minimal there means with respect to *divisibilty,* as this is relevant for ideal-generation. This translates to the (partial) order given by coordinate wise comaparison in $N^n$.

Answer (score 0):

### The exponents of an $n$-variable monomial correspond to an $n$-tuple.

- The polynomial ring $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ consists of all polynomials in the $n$ variables $x_1,\ldots, x_n$.
- You can associate any *monomial* with the (ordered) tuple of its exponents. For example, the monomial $x^7y^5z^3 \in k[x,y,z]$ corresponds to the tuple $\langle 7, 5, 3\rangle$. The monomial $x^2z \in k[x,y,z]$ corresponds to the tuple $\langle 2, 0, 1\rangle$.    Every monomial corresponds to the unique tuple of its exponents, and vice versa.
- If an ideal is generated by a collection $A$ of monomials, we can consider the corresponding set of *exponent tuples* corresponding to the monomials in $A$. These form a subset of $\mathbb{N}^n$, and by Wikipedia's formulation of Dickson's lemma, there must exist a *finite* minimal subcollection.
- Conversely, if $B$ is any subset of $\mathbb{N}^n$, map those tuples onto their corresponding monomials in a polynomial ring $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ and consider the ideal generated by them. Then the monomial formulation of Dickson's lemma says that there must be a finite basis for this ideal. If you take the exponent tuples corresponding to that finite basis, you get a finite set of minimal tuples for $B$.